# SQL Server : XML value returns Scalar and seems I need to convert it twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this line of SQL:

```
DECLARE @temp_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = @data.value('/metaData[1]/item[@key="Id"][1]/@value', 'uniqueidentifier')
```

So, `@data` is a parameter to my stored procedure. `@data XML`

I want to pass a value out of the XML into another stored procedure, as you can see it's the `Id` field in the xml.

```
@data.value('/metaData[1]/item[@key="Id"][1]/@value', 'uniqueidentifier')
```

This pulls out and converts the `Id` value to a `Uniqueidentifier` however when I assign this to a variable and pass it to the stored procedure:

```
EXEC my_sproc @Id = @temp_Id
```

I get an error

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure Some_Sproc, Line __
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@tempId".

Looking around, people are suggesting to wrap the `@data.value(...` in a `CONVERT( DATA_TYPE, VALUE )` which seems slightly absurd.

**-- EDIT --**

I reckon there could also be a chance of my SQL Server Management Studio intellisense being out of sync....

**-- CODE --**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sproc_CB8PutNotification]
    @message_type NVARCHAR(250),
    @utc_timestamp DATETIME2,
    @data XML
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @temp_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = @data.value('/metaData[1]/item[@key="Id"][1]/@value', 'uniqueidentifier')

    EXEC dbo.SaveNotification @Id = @tempId;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   -- some catch code
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc
   @id  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
SELECT @id;
GO

DECLARE @data XML = 
  '<metaData><item key="Id" value="903e9859-f8fd-4163-9303-b43f89fe977f"/>
   </metaData>';

DECLARE @temp_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
       = @data.value('/metaData[1]/item[@key="Id"][1]/@value', 'uniqueidentifier');

EXEC my_proc @id = @temp_id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/JDPM9165)**</kbd>

---

I suspect you have `GO` betweens calls and variable is not visible between batches like:

```
DECLARE @data XML = 
    '<metaData>
          <item key="Id" value="903e9859-f8fd-4163-9303-b43f89fe977f"/>
     </metaData>';
DECLARE @temp_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
      =  @data.value('/metaData[1]/item[@key="Id"][1]/@value', 'uniqueidentifier');
GO

EXEC my_proc @id = @temp_id;
```

> Error(s), warning(s):
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@temp_id".

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/BUU48198)**</kbd>

Or you have nested calls and variable is out of scope.

**EDIT:**

Typo **`@temp_id`** <> **`@tempId`**:

```
DECLARE @temp_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 
       @data.value('/metaData[1]/item[@key="Id"][1]/@value', 'uniqueidentifier')

EXEC dbo.SaveNotification @Id = @tempId;
```

<kbd>**[`Working code`](http://rextester.com/NVFEU28526)**</kbd>

You've mixed two naming conventions. The key point is to be consistent. It can save a lot of headaches.

Comment: It is as you see it, a declare then the sproc call

Comment: @CallumLinington I see only some code lines. Please provide entire script with full SP body and how you call it. You could make demo as I did.

Comment: Your demo is what I have got.

Comment: @CallumLinington IT Crowd solution: `Have you tried to turn it off and on again?`

Comment: @CallumLinington Check carefully variable names :)

Comment: Yeah just saw it... problem with creating a sproc in the evening and finishing off in the morning... not the greatest of error messages though